# Teradata SQL Week Number - Week 1 starting 1st Jan with weeks aligned to specific day of the week

Tags: sql, teradata, week-number, sql-date-functions

my first post on here so please be gentle...

I'm trying to create a week number variable in Teradata (SQL) that does the following:

- Week 1 always starts on 1st January of the given year
- Week numbers increment on the specified day of the week

For example: If Saturday was the specified day of the week:

- 2019-01-01 would be the start of week 1, 2019, changing to week 2 on 2019-01-05
- 2020-01-01 would be the start of week 1, 2020, changing to week 2 on 2020-01-04

I have come up wit the following based on an Excel function however it doesn't quite work as expected:

`ROUND(((DATE_SPECIFIED - CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_SPECIFIED) || '-01-01' AS DATE) + 1) - ((DATE_SPECIFIED - DATE '0001-01-06') MOD 7 + 1) + 10) / 7) AS REQUIRED_WEEK`

The last digit of the section `- DATE '0001-01-06'` deals with the specified day of the week, where '0001-01-01' would be Monday.

This works in some cases however for some years, the first week number is showing as 0 where it should be 1, e.g. 1st Jan 2018 / 2019 are fine whereas 1st Jan 2020 is not.

Any ideas to correct this would be gratefully received.

Many thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `NEXT_DAY` for both the specified date and Jan 1st of that year, e.g. for Saturday as week start:

```
(Next_Day(DATE_SPECIFIED,'SAT') - Next_Day(Trunc(DATE_SPECIFIED,'yyyy'),'SAT')) / 7 +1
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth - that worked perfectly. A lot more elegant than my solution too.!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I'm a bit week on Teradata functions.  But the idea is to get the start of the *second* week.  This follows the rule:

```
Jan 1      weekday (TD)     2nd week
Sunday        1               01-02
Monday        2               01-08
Tuesday       3               01-07
Wednesday     4               01-06
Thursday      5               01-05
Friday        6               01-04
Saturday      7               01-03
```

I think the following logic calculates this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when td_day_of_week(cast(extract(year from DATE_SPECIFIED) || '-01-01' as date) ) = 1
             then cast(extract(year from DATE_SPECIFIED) + '-01-02' as date)
             else extract(year from DATE_SPECIFIED) + 10 - cast(td_day_of_week(cast(extract(year from DATE_SPECIFIED) || '-01-01') as date)
from t;
```

Then do you your week calculate either from the second week or subtract one more week to get when the first week really starts.

Comment: Hi @Gordon - thanks for the response. I had a play with your response but couldn't get it to work - it kept throwing an error.

Comment: it initially fails as the statement is incomplete. I added `) end) as required_week` however this then fails with _error 3706 - expected something between string / unicode char literal and )._